# Evaluate triple integral using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Hello i cant figure out how to evaluate this integral and find a volume for a triple integral which is given by $z=x^2+y^2 \text{ and } z = x+y$ this figure for what i found is paraboloid intersected by a straight plane. I have tried to find the intersection of the two figures but it turns out it is $r^2 = r$ if i put $x^2+y^2$ for $r^2$ and $r$ for $x+y$ i i left with the integral $$\iint_k \int_r^{r^2} r \,dr\,d\varphi$$ I evaluate it and i get $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_?^? r(r^2 -r) \,d\varphi\,dr$$ now i am not sure for the last boundaries please can someone help me i lost so many hours on this problem when there are no intersection of the figures i can solve it but i stuck here. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: If $r^2=x^2+y^2$ then $r\not=x+y$ Recall that $x=r\cos(θ)$ and $y=r\sin(θ)$

Comment: @Robert Z I will have that in mind. Sorry for the easy question but i am not good at math i still learn. Btw the 3d calculator is life saver. even you can see the projection there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by letting $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, the inequality $x^2+y^2\leq z\leq x+y$ implies
$$r\leq \cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)$$
which is a disc in the $xy$-plane centered at $(1/2,1/2)$ and of radius $1/\sqrt{2}$.
Hence the volume is given by
$$\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\int_{r=0}^{\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}
\int_{z=r^2}^{r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))}dz\, rdr\,d\theta$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Does that mean the boundaries are from $0 to 1/2$ when i integrate r and the circle is centered at the point 1/2 for y and 1/2 for x with radius 1/2. Yes i think i should solve it from here @Robert Z thank you a lot.

Comment: I edited my answer: now the computation is written in cylindrical coordinates, Is it clear now? Try to visualize the domain by using https://www.geogebra.org/3d

Answer (score 0):

One way for finding the volume is using symmetry about $x=y$, by this we can rotate the volume and find the integration limits, then we want to find the volume between $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=y$, so after visualization
$${\bf V}=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}} \int_{x^2+y^2}^y1dzdydx=\color{blue}{\dfrac{\pi}{32}}$$

Comment: @Robert Z I wrote down the solution and understand it the only think i struggle to understand is how to calculate the limits for Theta. Can you give me a tip please.

Comment: Thank you this works also.

Comment: You are welcome